# Pythonのlistの最初の項目を削除して取り出したい

Tags: python

```py
num_list = [[[10,20,30],[123,34,20]],[[30,40,50],[123,132,4]]]
```

上のような配列を下のように最初の一つだけ削除して取り出したいのですが、効率のいい方法はないでしょうか？

```py
num_list = [[[20,30],[34,20]],[[40,50],[132,4]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常のループだと以下のような処理になるはず

```py
num_list = [[[10,20,30],[123,34,20]],[[30,40,50],[123,132,4]]]

for lists in num_list:
  print(lists)
  for lst in lists:
    print(f'\t{lst} => {lst[1:]}')
```

```
[[10, 20, 30], [123, 34, 20]]
    [10, 20, 30] => [20, 30]
    [123, 34, 20] => [34, 20]
[[30, 40, 50], [123, 132, 4]]
    [30, 40, 50] => [40, 50]
    [123, 132, 4] => [132, 4]
```

それをリスト内包表記にするとこんな感じ

```py
[[lst[1:]for lst in lists]for lists in num_list]
```

---

効率というのが速度を指しているなら, `timeit` で調べることができます

Answer (score 0):

効率的かどうかは不明ですが、以下は numpy.ndarray のセレクタを使う方法です。

```py
import numpy as np

num_list = [[[10, 20, 30], [123, 34, 20]], [[30, 40, 50], [123, 132, 4]]]
print(np.array(num_list)[:,:,1:].tolist())

=>
[[[20, 30], [34, 20]], [[40, 50], [132, 4]]]
```

Comment: 言い方が適切ではなかったですね。簡単にという形でした。ありがとうございます。